# overriding methods while calling constructor

Tags: java, class

I saw these codes.

I've never seen such constructor, but I guess that it creates a new A instance with the implementation of a abstract method.

what is it called?

```
new A() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent() {
        dosomething();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you referring to an **anonymous class**?  Its when you provide an implementation but never define a named class.  In other words, you are providing an object in-place; you cannot reuse that definition elsewhere because you never wrote `class MyClass {}`, which is why it's "anonymous".

[See this.](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This is an Object of type A that overrided the onEvent method of class A. This is called anonymous class which overrided a method